# how to find the element in a list whose value is closest to 0

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Suppose I have a list, 
`x = [-7, 15, -6, -19, 27, 71, 3, -84, -16, -4, -15, -28, 18, 62, -93]`

how to find the closest value to zero?

Answer (score 3):

Use `min()` function with custom key:

```
x = [-7, 15, -6, -19, 27, 71, 3, -84, -16, -4, -15, -28, 18, 62, -93]

print(min(x, key=abs))
```

Prints:

```
3
```